# Generating a basic school schedule

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to implement a very basic, very simple version of generating a school schedule from a pre-determined list of shifts and a pre-determined list of people.

**Constrains and basic setup**

For the sake of example, let us assume the following problem data:

5- people, let's call them A,B,C,D,E want their respective schedules to be assigned.

Each person has a list of shifts, previously chosen.

There are 5 days per week, and let us assume that each day has 3 shifts, so, we have a matrix with 3 rows, 5 columns. Cells that represent the shifts are numbered from top to bottom left to right, starting with 1.

For the list:

A = {1,2,3,5,10,11}

B = {6,7,1,3,8,15}

C = {2,6,8,9,12,13}

D = {3,4,5,6,7,8}

E = {6,8,10,11,13,14}

After attributing all the shifts, the schedule would be:

A - 5,10,11

B - 1,7,15

C - 2,6,12

D - 3,4,9

E - 8,13,14

How can I generalize this concept to a real-world case, with let's say 20 people, 40 shifts, each person choosing 2 out of a list of 8 shifts.

My code is below:

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    #include <set>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;

    #define OPT_DEGREE 300

    #define DEBUG 0
    #define vpbvi vector<pair<bool,vector<ULL> > >
    #define ULL unsigned long long

    static string dict[20];

    void showV(vector<ULL> & v)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << v[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    inline bool do_vectors_intersect(vector<ULL> v1, vector<ULL> v2)
    {
        unsigned long long int target_sz = v1.size()+v2.size();
        set<ULL> s;
        for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
            s.insert(v1[i]);
        for(int j = 0; j < v2.size(); j++)
            s.insert(v2[j]);

        return !(static_cast<ULL>(s.size()) == target_sz); //True se ha intersecçao False c.c.
    }

    void generateAllPossibleShifts(vector<vector<ULL> > & auxiliar, vector<ULL> & _shifts, int N, int K)
    {
        string bitmask(K, 1); // K leading 1's
        bitmask.resize(N, 0); // N-K trailing 0's

         // print integers and permute bitmask
         do {
                vector<ULL> aux;
                for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // [0..N-1] integers
                {
                    if (bitmask[i])
                    {
                        aux.push_back(_shifts[i]);
                        if(DEBUG){
                            cout << " " << _shifts[i];}
                    }
                }
                if(DEBUG){
                    cout << endl << aux.size() << " Done. Create Pair and add to scheudle." << endl;}
                    pair<bool,vector<ULL> > pbvi = make_pair(true,aux);

                    for(int i = 0; i < aux.size();i++)
                        if(DEBUG){
                        cout << "aux[" <<i<<"] = " << pbvi.second[i] << endl;}
                    auxiliar.push_back(aux);
                   // fullVec.push_back(pbvi);
                    aux.resize(0); //vector is cleared here
                    if(DEBUG){
                    cout << "Clear vec" << endl;
                    cout << pbvi.second.size() << " Done" << endl;
                    cout <<  endl;}
            } while ( prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()));
    }

    vector<ULL> SumVecs(vector<ULL> & a, vector<ULL> & b)
    {
        vector<ULL> newVec;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
            newVec.push_back(a[i]);
        for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
            newVec.push_back(b[i]);
        return newVec;
    }

    void AppendToFirst(vector<ULL> & fst, vector<ULL> & snd, int ind)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < snd.size(); k++)
        fst.push_back(snd[k]);
    }

    void OptimizeBeforeNextPassLeft(vector<vector<ULL> > & bsc, vector<vector<ULL> > & arg2)
    {
        int opt = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < bsc.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < arg2.size(); j++)
            {
                if(do_vectors_intersect(bsc[i],arg2[j])==true){
                    arg2.erase(remove(arg2.begin(), arg2.end(), arg2[j]), arg2.end());
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    void OptimizeBeforeNextPassRight(vector<vector<ULL> > & bsc, vector<vector<ULL> > & arg2)
    {
        int opt = 0;
        for(int i = bsc.size()-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < arg2.size(); j++)
            {
                if(do_vectors_intersect(bsc[i],arg2[j])==true){
                    bsc.erase(bsc.begin()+i);
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    void HardOptimize(vector<vector<ULL> > & bsc, vector<vector<ULL> > & arg2)
    {
        int opt = 0;
        for(int i = bsc.size()-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < arg2.size(); j+=2)
            {
                if(do_vectors_intersect(bsc[i],arg2[j])==true){
                    bsc.erase(bsc.begin()+i);
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    //Recursive Function that filters bad attempts and uses "basic" look-ahead technique to narrow search space
    //while building an iterative solution. Can still be optimized.
     void ExpandSearchSpace(vector<vector<vector<ULL> > > & v, vector<vector<ULL> > & buildSol, int guesslvl, vector<vector<ULL> > & placeholder)
    {
       if(guesslvl==4) //Num de pessoas-1
       {
           // cout << "inside ret " << endl << buildSol.size();
            placeholder = buildSol;
           return;
       }
       else
       {
            vector<vector<ULL> > BuildSolCp;
            const int ssz = buildSol.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < ssz;i++)
            {
                vector<ULL> arg1 = buildSol[i];
                const int ssz2 = v[guesslvl+1].size();
               //cout << "arg1.sz() = " << arg1.size() << endl;
                for(int j = 0; j < ssz2;j++)
                {
                    if(do_vectors_intersect(buildSol[i], v[guesslvl+1][j])==false){
                 //   cout << "Iter " << guesslvl << "   " << buildSol[i].size() << " ";
                   vector<ULL> arg2 = v[guesslvl+1][j];
                 // cout << "arg2 " << arg1.size() << " --- ";
                  vector<ULL> auxi = SumVecs(arg1,arg2);
                 // cout << "OLFOFKODSJFDSIHFDSFDS" << endl;
                     BuildSolCp.push_back(auxi);
                   //  cout << "PUSHDED SDUSHFUDSHF"<<endl;

                    }
                }
            }

            guesslvl++;
            if(BuildSolCp.size()> 1000){
            cout << "WE neeed optimize Jon" << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < BuildSolCp.size();i++)
            showV(BuildSolCp[i]);
            vector<vector<ULL> > s= v[guesslvl+1];
            //vector<vector<ULL> > s3= v[guesslvl+4];
          //  vector<vector<ULL> > s4= v[guesslvl+5];
         //  OptimizeBeforeNextPassLeft(BuildSolCp, s);
         OptimizeBeforeNextPassLeft(buildSol,v[guesslvl+2]);

          //  OptimizeBeforeNextPassRight(BuildSolCp, s);}
           // OptimizeFromBothSidesAtOnce(BuildSolCp, v[guesslvl+1][j]);
           }

            cout << BuildSolCp.size() << " " << guesslvl << endl;

           ExpandSearchSpace(v,BuildSolCp, guesslvl, placeholder);
       }
      // cout << "end" << endl;
    }

    void ShowPrettyScheudle(vector<vector<ULL> > sol)
    {
        vector<int> scheudle(15);
        for(int j = 0; j <= 10; j+=5){
            for(int i = j; i < j+5; i++)
            {
                cout << sol[0][i] << "\t | ";
            }
            cout << endl;}

    }

    int main()
    {
        static vector<vector<ULL> > WorkerVec1,WorkerVec2,WorkerVec3,WorkerVec4, WorkerVec5;
        static vector<vector<ULL> > WorkerVec6,WorkerVec7,WorkerVec8,WorkerVec9, WorkerVec10;
        static vector<vector<ULL> > WorkerVec11,WorkerVec12,WorkerVec13,WorkerVec14, WorkerVec15;
        static vector<vector<ULL> > WorkerVec16,WorkerVec17,WorkerVec18,WorkerVec19, WorkerVec20;
        vector<vector<ULL> > sol;
        static vector<vector<vector<ULL>>> v;

        vector<ULL> v1{5,10,11,3,1,2}, v2{1,7,3,15,6,8} ,v3{2,6,12,8,13,9}, v4{3,4,5,6,7,8},v5{6,8,10,11,13,14};
        generateAllPossibleShifts(WorkerVec1, v1,6,3);
        generateAllPossibleShifts(WorkerVec2, v2,6,3);
        generateAllPossibleShifts(WorkerVec3, v3,6,3);
        generateAllPossibleShifts(WorkerVec4, v4,6,3);
        generateAllPossibleShifts(WorkerVec5, v5,6,3);
        v.insert(v.end(), {WorkerVec1,WorkerVec2, WorkerVec3,WorkerVec4, WorkerVec5} );
        cout << "SIZE OF v[0] in main is " << v[0].size() << endl; //20
        for(int i = 0; i < v[0].size(); i++)
        {
            sol.push_back(v[0][i]);
        }
        cout << sol.size() << endl; //20
        vector<vector<ULL> > plcholder;
        cout << "OMG " << plcholder.size()<<endl;
        ExpandSearchSpace(v,sol,0,plcholder);

        cout << sol.size() << endl;
        for(int i = plcholder.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
            cout << plcholder[i].size() << endl;
            if(plcholder[i].size()==15){
                 cout << "FUCK YEA ";showV(plcholder[i]);
                 cout << endl << endl;
                vector<vector<ULL> > vect{plcholder[i]};
                ShowPrettyScheudle(vect);
                break;}
                }
        cout << endl;
       // cout << endl << Ans[0].size() << " " << Ans[1].size() << " " << Ans[2].size() << " " << Ans[3].size();
        return 0;
    }
```

I know the code is messy, but, its essence is simple:

I basically do a brute force where on each pass I "accumulate" blocks of 3 possible shifts and compare them with the next set of possible shifts until I reach the end with only possible shifts selected.

I tried to think in terms of a simple DP formulation, even graphs, but, I'm totally stuck... Maybe thinking in terms of the individual shifts instead of "blocks of shifts" is better, but, right now, I'm at a loss. 
I've been over this thing for 2 days now and it's sincerely getting on my nerves

Comment: In the real-word these kind of problems are tackled through Constraint-Programming, Integer-Programming, SAT-solving, Heuristics/Metaheuristics and Hybrids of these (because these problems are hard). Brute-force will hit a computational-limit very early!

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer! I am aware of CP and IP, but my question was mostly if a "pruned" brute-force would solve a domain with 20 people and 40 shifts, which I think its doable bt brute-force or even backtracking after some pre-processing. My issue is how to do this pre-processing

Comment: Well, the fact that it's probably np-hard tells us, that there are instances of 20 people and 40 shifts, that are tough to tackle with any algorithm. I'm not sure what kind of preprocessing you want to do. It really sounds, like you want to implement a CP-solver based approach by yourself (including forward-checking; backtracking and co.). There is also another modelling-problem/question: the people are chosing shifts: what does that mean? Are these fixed (sometimes infeasible) or are they *wishes* -> in this case you need some regulization/penalty in your objective (which calls for MIQP).

Comment: It represents merely wishes, ie, shifts that the people WOULD like to do, but can not necessarily accomplish

Comment: In this case, you would want to have a feasible solution, which agrees somehow with these wishes. I cannot stop to recommend MIP/MIQP-approaches then, because you would need some optimization-function which reflects the agreement with these a-priori chosings. But you have to describe some metric first on how to score this / how to punish failed wishes (which can make a huge difference; e.g. linear or quadratic penalties; if 5 chosen and 3/4 possible; which is better). You could try your purely combinatorial way of tackling this, but it's much harder to balance the missings of wishes then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there are n people, m shifts available, and you want to assign s (necessarily s <= m/n) shifts to each person.  This problem can be modelled as the problem of finding a [maximum matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs) in a bipartite graph.  A matching is a set of edges such that no vertex is used in more than one edge; a maximum matching is a matching of maximum possible size.  To construct the graph:

- In part A, create s vertices v_{i,1}, ..., v_{i,s} for each person i.
- In part B, create a single vertex for each shift.
- Whenever person i can use shift j, insert s edges (v_{i,1}, j), (v_{i,2}, j), ..., (v_{i,s}, j).

The resulting graph is bipartite, since there are no edges between 2 vertices in A, or between 2 vertices in B.  You can find a maximum matching in O(sqrt(|V|)|E|) time using the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm in the first link; this will give you an optimal solution (every person is assigned s shifts) if one exists.  Here |V| = sn+m, and |E| = O(snm) since in the worst case it could be that every person lists every shift as a possibility, so the overall time complexity will be O(sqrt(sn+m)snm).

### Counterexample to Ari's solution

[Ari Hietanen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37861043/47984) is a good heuristic, but it can fail to find a solution even when one exists, as the following example problem instance shows.

Suppose we have 8 people A, B, ..., H, and 8 shifts 1, 2, ..., 8, we want to assign each person one shift, and the matrix of possible shifts looks like this:

```
  12345678
A XXXXX...
B XXXX....
C XXXX....
D XXXX....
E XXXX....
F ....XXXX
G .....XXX
H .....XXX
```

where an X indicates that the person in that row could do the shift in that column.

Ari's algorithm will first select shift (column) 5, since with just 2 people (A and F) this shift can be used by fewer people than all the other shifts (which all can be used by at least 3 people).  Since at this point neither A nor F have any shifts assigned, it's undecided whether it will pick A or F to assign shift 5 to, so it's possible that it will pick F -- and certainly, if it breaks ties by choosing the person who has the fewest possible shifts available, it will do so (since F has 4 possible shifts, and A has 5).  But as soon as it makes this choice, it has no way to solve the problem, since this means that the 4 shifts 1, 2, 3 and 4 need to somehow be split among the 5 people A, B, C, D and E, which isn't possible.  To see that a solution does exist, suppose we assign shift 5 to A instead: now we just need to spread the 4 shifts 1, 2, 3 and 4 across the *4* people B, C, D and E, and the 3 shifts 6, 7 and 8 across the 3 people F, G and H, which can easily be done.

Answer (score 3):

As your case it quite simple, you could try following algorithm,

1. First link the shifts to person
2. Loop over all the shifts

   3. Pick the shift which least persons linked to it
   4. Assign the shift to the person among these with least shifts already assigned.

This algorithm works in O(N*M), where N is the shifts and M is persons. It also always finds a solution, but **not** necessarily the correct one. See the answer of j_random_hacker.

Below is one implementation which does not check that input data is valid. I changed shift 15 to 0 to map with vector indices.

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class VectorComp{
public:
  bool operator()(const std::vector<int>& v1,const std::vector<int>& v2){
    if (v1.size()==0) return false;
    if (v2.size()==0) return true;
    return v1.size()<v2.size();
  }
};

int main(){
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> personToShift{{1,2,3,5,10,11},
                                              {6,7,1,3,8,0},
                                              {2,6,8,9,12,13},
                                              {3,4,5,6,7,8},
                                              {6,8,10,11,13,14}};

  //Map shifts to persons
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> shiftToPerson(15);
  for (size_t i=0;i<personToShift.size();++i){
    for (auto s:personToShift[i]){
      shiftToPerson[s].push_back(i);
    }
  }

  //Result vector
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> res(personToShift.size());

  for (size_t i=0;i<shiftToPerson.size();++i){
    auto minPersonsForShift = std::min_element(shiftToPerson.begin(),
                                              shiftToPerson.end(),
                                              VectorComp());//Find shift with minimum persons
    size_t shift=minPersonsForShift-shiftToPerson.begin();
    size_t minShifts=shiftToPerson.size();
    size_t minPerson=0;
    for (auto person:*minPersonsForShift){//Find person in shift with   minimum shifts so far
      if (res[person].size()<minShifts){
        minPerson=person;
        minShifts=res[person].size();
      }
    }
    res[minPerson].push_back(shift);//Update the result
    shiftToPerson[shift].clear();//Mark the shift assigned by clearing the vector
  }

  for (size_t i=0;i<res.size();++i){//Print the result
    std::cout << char(('A'+i)) << " - ";
    for (auto t:res[i]){
      std::cout << t << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }    
}
```

Output:

```
A - 1 2 11 
B - 0 7 3 
C - 9 12 13 
D - 4 5 6 
E - 14 10 8
```

Comment: This is a good heuristic, but it can fail to find a solution even when one exists -- see the last part of my answer.